# Spring - in controller I find data from database, but I can't delete these data from database

Tags: java, spring, controller, spring-data-jpa

According to the logic of the application, I have a controller to remove the recycle bin. By the link we get the session id, by it we search for the user in the database and delete all the invoices associated with it.

```java
@RequestMapping(path="/basket/del/{sessId}",  method=RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public BasketListReply delAllProducts(@PathVariable String sessId){
    BasketListReply rep = new BasketListReply();       
    try {    
        //check if session exist
        List<Long> delList = userService.findInvoiceBySessionId(sessId);
        //delList contain list of invoices id to delete
        if(delList != null) {
            for(int i=0;i<delList.size();i++){
                invoiceService.delInvoice(delList.get(i));
            }                
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        rep.retcode = -1;
        rep.error_message = e.getMessage();
    }
    return rep;
}
```

With method findInvoiceBySessionId() I get list of invoices from collection () to delete.

```java
public List findInvoiceBySessionId(String sessId) throws Exception{
        List list = new ArrayList();        
        List<Appuser> users = findUserBySessionId(sessId);
            if(!users.isEmpty()) {
                //if exist, then extract invoices for this user
                Appuser u = users.get(0);
                List<Invoice> invoices = (List<Invoice>)u.getInvoiceCollection();                
                for(Invoice inv:invoices) {
                    list.add(inv.getOrderId());
                }                               
            }     
        return list;
    }
```

Method delInvoice() I use to delete invoice from repository.

```java
public void delInvoice(Long orderId){
    if(invoiceRepository.findOne(orderId) == null) {
        return;
    }
    invoiceRepository.delete(orderId);
}
```

File Appuser.java (field that contain collection of Invoices):

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userId")
    private Collection<Invoice> invoiceCollection;
```

Did I understand correctly that I can not in one controller and extract data from the database via JPA and delete the same data ... since the deletion should go in a separate transaction.
Or am I doing something wrong?
When I delete the data by redirecting the request to the controller to delete the data, everything works fine.

Comment: so whats the error? or just deletion is not cascaded?

Comment: Operations go through, but the data in the tables remain in place and are not deleted. And I don't understand why.

Comment: The nuance is that I can not delete exactly the invoice, the link to which I received from the appuser table. In this case, I can freely delete the neighboring invoice. It seems that after I read the collection of invoices from the applet, I'm still inside a transaction and I can not delete what I'm currently connected to.

Comment: Using the experiment method, I was able to find out that the connection with Appuser does not allow to delete. If I manually assign user.setInvoiceCollection (null), then it is deleted without problems.                                                      Appuser.java:                                                                               @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userId")
    private Collection<Invoice> invoiceCollection;